# can i launch contacts app on android and actually get the selected contacts mobile number in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to launch the contacts app and get the contact number selected after in any flutter app.

I've managed to only launch the `url` using the `url_launcher` package but could not find a way to return the selected contact back to the app,

Please can someone tell me how can we do this in flutter mobile apps.

Many Thanks,
Mahi

Comment: Bear in mind that you can do android/IOS call if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with the `url_launcher` package. There is already a [`contact_picker` package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/contact_picker)  available for flutter that allows you to pick a contact.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks @Hemanth Raj you are a star mate I will try the package and let you know if that works thank you very much.

Comment: Ah that's okay! Just accept the answer if it helped.